# Magento 2.2 admin login screen does not load CSS

Tags: magento2.2

I have a store on `Magento v2.2.5`. It suddenly stop displaying `gui` for admin login screen. It display `un` styled form box for login(See attached image).

[image: Unstyled Login Form]

Login function works and dashboard pages are working well. 
Kindly suggest some solution...
I tried all these command via `SSH`

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .htaccess file in pub and pub/static folder. If you accidentally deleted it, you can copy from here https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2/pub

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm first you have `.htaccess` file here on this path

> pub/static/.htaccess

If that is available there then please try to run below command in following sequence.

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will helpful to you!

Comment: Hello Kishan Savaliya, thanks for prompt reply... Now i got the main problem in my store but still unable to resolve it. Actually i create a mirror site in my hosting in which i got issues parent store works fine but the mirror one looks odd. The reason i find that mirror site still uses parent store's css & media url's which create all the fuss.... the secure base url and insucure base url are also set correctly, Kindly suggest some solution.

Comment: Can you please explain me with some example? I really didn't understand your issue.